# Print selected fields in page tpl Drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes

For some reasons, I have to customize the display of the content node programmaticaly, mixing content from other sources.

Instead of making a `print(render($page['content']` which outputs all the content, I need to access to selected parts of the content (for instance, value of a text field, url of a PDF file, etc.). I am using this approach:

`print render( $page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$nid]['body']['#object']->field_subtitle_product["und"][0]["value"]);`

Would it be correct or is there a more straighforward method? ( I don't want to low to node.tpl.php anyway).

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you explain why you are not using the node template?

Comment: I want to put some elements outside of the area, in the template. I have reduced the code to: `print render( $node->field_subtitle_product["und"][0]["value"] );` I doubt it can be shortened more. Just wanted to know if this is a good approach, other approach is to render all content and use css to change position in screen, to hide elements, but I find this approach cleaner and can be used in different views.

Answer (score 3):

First, If you want to print selected field then you should to do it in `node.tpl.php` and not in `page`. There are many ways to do this :

If you just need to render the fields in default way, you can go to `Admin > Content Type > Your Content Type > Manage Display` and hide the fields you want.

If you want to do it through template files then you can use it using :

```
hide($content['field_name']);
print render($content['field_name']);
```

You can just remove `print render($content);` and write :

```
print render($content['field_name']);
print render($content['field_name2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with it, so long as it's done correctly - some things to note:

- make sure the page.tpl.php is specific to the content type; this will reduce overhead and potential errors when content types don't contain that field
- this can also be done using blocks and enabling php editing if you don't want a custom tpl.
- you should use [field_view_value](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7) and [field_get_item](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7) or similar instead of ['und'][0]['value']